# No calls and messages before first call/message

Tags: missed-calls, samsung-galaxy-spica

My Samsung Galaxy Spica (GT-I5700) has this problem: when it first starts or resume from airplane mode (i.e. when turning off airplane mode), the GSM network status appears to be normal (full signal) but the phone won't receive calls or SMS. Only after I made a call or send a message then all the missed calls and SMSes came at once.

How do I restore the normal function?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the problem comes from the handset? Sometimes, it's only the time required to be paired with the closest BTS (or nodeB in 3G), and you can't do anything but require explicitly the network by placing a call.

The most common way to do this is to call your answer machine, which is free and always instructive :)